# Custom URI for android application

Tags: android, uri, nfc

I want to call the activity `Tap In` when an NFC Tag is tapped to my phone using URI Scheme. How can I define this in android manifest?... not to launch an app, but only open content in that app.
In data, how is host, path, and scheme defined and how should I write them?
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S5 and NTAG216.

```
package="com.example.nani.mrt">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainHome">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

    <activity android:name=".TapIn">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host=""
                android:path=""
                android:scheme="" />

            <data android:scheme="" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NFCTourguide" />
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeNavigation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_navigation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".StudentVerification" />
    <activity android:name=".Normal" />
    <activity android:name=".OKUVerification" />
    <activity android:name=".SeniorVerification" />

</application>
```